# Trees with tangent curved arrows

Tags: arrows, tikz-trees, tikz-arrows, linguistics

The arrow controlled by

```
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (pe)..controls +(south west: 50) and  +(south: 50) .. (re);
```

dissects the tree. I want it to curve round the bottom-most node of the tree. I was told that I could not use a Bezier curve to do this, and would have to use a tangent curve. How can I do this?

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
    \usepackage{tikz-qtree}
    \usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
    \usepackage{ulem}

    \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), every tree     node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}, level distance = 16ex, scale= 0.5]   
      \Tree [. {\formula{\exists z [sample(z) \land \forall x \exists y      [Company (y) \land Representative-of(x,y) \rightarrow saw(x, z)]]} \\    \formula{t}   }     [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists z [sample' (z)} \\    \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} \hspace{0.1cm} }  [.{\formula{\lambda P.\lambda Q. \exists z [P(z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} }  ] [.{ \formula{\lambda d. sample'(d):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)}  }  ]  ] [. { \formula{\lambda m. \forall x \exists z [company' (z)  \land R.of(x, z)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow \exists y [sample' (y) \land saw'(x, y)]} \\ \formula{((e \linimp t)}  } [.\node (re) {$m : e$}; ] [.{ \formula{\forall x \exists z [company' (z)  \land R.of(x, z)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow \exists y [sample' (y) \land saw'(x, y)]} \\ \formula{t} } [.{ \formula{\lambda Q. \forall x \exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land R.of(x, z) \rightarrow Q(x)} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} }  [.{ \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall x [P (x)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Q(x)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))}} ] [.{\formula{\lambda n. \exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land R.of(n',z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t} }     [.\node (ue) {$n : e$}; ] [.{\formula{\exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land R.of(n',z)]: t} }          [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} \hspace{0.1cm} } [.{\formula{\lambda P.\lambda Q. \exists z [P(z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} }  ] [.{ \formula{\lambda d. company'(d):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)}  } ]             ] [.{\formula{\lambda l. R.of(n',l'):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} }       [.\node (ne) {$l : e$}; ] [.{\formula{R.of(n',l'):} \\ \formula{(t)} }       [.\node [circle,draw] (le) {$n : e$} ; ] [.{\formula{\lambda x. R.of(x,l'):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} }       [.{\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. R.of(x,y):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp } \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} } ] [.{\formula{l':e} }     [. {\formula{\lambda x_e. x_e:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp e)} } ] [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {$l' : e$} ; ] ] ]         ]                ]             ] ]         ] [.{\formula{\lambda k'. saw(k',m):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} } [.\node (te) {$k' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k',m'):} \\ \formula{t} }          [.\node [circle,draw] (se) {$k' : e$} ; ] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m'):} \\ \formula{(e  \linimp  t)} }   [.{\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp} \\ \formula{(e  \linimp  t)} } ] [.\node [circle,draw] (pe) {$m : e$} ; ] ] ]                  ]             ]           ] ] 
  \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:10) and +(south:10)    .. (ue);   
  \draw[semithick, dashed, ->]
  (me)..controls +(south west:11) and +(south:11) .. (ne);
  \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (se)..controls +(south west:1) and +(south:1) .. (te);    
  \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (pe)..controls +(south west: 50) and  +(south: 50) .. (re);    
  \end{tikzpicture}  
  \end{document}
```

Likewise, I am having the same problems with the following two trees, and would like to prevent the arrows dissecting the trees (as they currently do):

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
    \usepackage{tikz-qtree}
    \usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
    \usepackage{ulem}

    \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}, level distance = 17ex, scale= 0.5]   
   \Tree  [.t [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} \hspace{0.1cm} } [.{\formula{\lambda P.\lambda Q. \exists z [P(z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} } ] [.{ \formula{\lambda d. company'(d):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)}  } ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda l'. \exists z [sample' (z)} \\ \formula{\land ]:} \\ \formula{\forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, z)]:}    \\ \formula{e \linimp t} \hspace{0.1cm} }      [.\node (ne) {$l' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{\exists z [sample' (z)} \\ \formula{\land ]:} \\ \formula{\forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, z)]:}    \\ \formula{t} \hspace{0.1cm} }       [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists z [sample' (z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} \hspace{0.1cm} } [.{\formula{\lambda P.\lambda Q. \exists z [P(z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} } ] [.{ \formula{\lambda d. sample'(d):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)}  } ] ] [.{ \formula{\lambda m'. \forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, m')]:} \\ \formula{e \linimp t} }        [.\node (re) {$m : e$}; ] [.{ \formula{\forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, m')]:} \\ \formula{t} }           [.{ \formula{\lambda Q. \forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Q(x)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} }          [.{ \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall x [P (x)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Q(x)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))}} ] [.{\formula{\lambda n'. R.of(n',l'):} \\ \formula{e \linimp t} }            [.\node (ue) {$n' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{R.of(n',l'):} \\ \formula{t} }                 [.\node [circle,draw] (le) {$n' : e$} ; ] [.{\formula{\lambda x. R.of(x,l'):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} }       [.{\formula{\lambda y \lambda x. R.of(x,y):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} }  ] [. \formula{l : e} [.{\formula{\lambda x_e. x_e:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp e)} } ] [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {$l' : e$} ; ]     ]       ]    ] ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda k'. saw(k',m'):} \\ \formula{e \linimp t} }     [.\node (te) {$k' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k',m'):} \\ \formula{t} }       [.\node [circle,draw] (se) {$k' : e$} ; ] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m'):} \\ \formula{(e  \linimp  t)} }  [.{\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp} \\ \formula{(e  \linimp  t)} } ] [.\node [circle,draw] (pe) {$m : e$} ; ] ]      ] ] ]            ]    ] ]                                                               ] 
 \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:1) and +(south:1) .. (ue);
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->]
  (me)..controls +(south west:15) and +(south:15) .. (ne);
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (se)..controls +(south west:1) and +(south:1) .. (te); 
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (pe)..controls +(south west:6) and +(south:6) .. (re);  
  \end{tikzpicture}  
  \end{document}
```

And the last tree:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
    \usepackage{tikz-qtree}
    \usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
    \usepackage{ulem}

    \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}, level distance = 15ex, scale= 0.5]   
   \Tree  [.t [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists z [sample' (z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} \hspace{0.1cm} } [.{\formula{\lambda P.\lambda Q. \exists z [P(z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} } ] [.{ \formula{\lambda d. sample'(d):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)}  } ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m'. \exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land \forall x [R.of(x,z)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, m')]]:} \\ \formula{t} \hspace{0.1cm} }  [.\node (re) {$m' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{\exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land \forall x [R.of(x,z)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, m')]]:} \\ \formula{t} \hspace{0.1cm} }       [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} \hspace{0.1cm} } [.{\formula{\lambda P.\lambda Q. \exists z [P(z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} } ] [.{ \formula{\lambda d. company'(d):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)}  } ] ] [.{ \formula{\lambda l'. \forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, m')]:} \\ \formula{e \linimp t} }  [.\node (ne) {$l' : e$}; ] [.{ \formula{\forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, m')]:} \\ \formula{t} }       [.{ \formula{\lambda Q. \forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Q(x)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))}}       [.{ \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall x [P (x)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Q(x)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))}} ] [.{\formula{\lambda n'. R.of(n',l'):} \\ \formula{e \linimp t} }         [.\node (ue) {$n' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{R.of(n',l'):} \\ \formula{t} }     [.\node [circle,draw] (le) {$n' : e$} ; ] [.{\formula{\lambda x. R.of(x,l'):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} }    [.{\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. R.of(x,y):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp} \\ \formula{e \linimp t)} } ] [. \formula{l : e} [.{\formula{\lambda x_e. x_e:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp e)} }  ] [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {$l' : e$} ; ]    ]     ]    ] ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda k'. saw(k',m'):} \\ \formula{e \linimp t} }         [.\node (te) {$k' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k',m'):} \\ \formula{t} }        [.\node [circle,draw] (se) {$k' : e$} ; ] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m'):} \\ \formula{(e  \linimp  t)} }           [.{\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp} \\ \formula{(e  \linimp  t)} }    ] [.\node [circle,draw] (pe) {$m' : e$} ; ] ]      ] ] ]            ]    ] ]                                                               ] 
 \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:1) and +(south:1) .. (ue);
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->]
  (me)..controls +(south west:11) and +(south:11) .. (ne);
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (se)..controls +(south west:1) and +(south:1) .. (te); 
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (pe)..controls +(south west:6) and +(south:6) .. (re);  
  \end{tikzpicture}   

  \end{document}
```

Comment: All the thing is to find appropriate control points; try   `\draw[overlay,semithick, dashed, ->] (pe)..controls +(south:8) and  (south:50) .. (re);` .

Comment: Ahhhhh, I didn't realise you could have +(south:8) and (south:50)... I thought the first had to be +(south west).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all boils down to choosing appropriate control points (I had to provide fake definitions for `\formula` and `\linimp` to process your code):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand\formula[1]{$#1$}
\newcommand\linimp{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), every tree     node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}, level distance = 16ex, scale= 0.5]   
      \Tree [. {\formula{\exists z [sample(z) \land \forall x \exists y      [Company (y) \land Representative-of(x,y) \rightarrow saw(x, z)]]} \\    \formula{t}   }     [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists z [sample' (z)} \\    \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} \hspace{0.1cm} }  [.{\formula{\lambda P.\lambda Q. \exists z [P(z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} }  ] [.{ \formula{\lambda d. sample'(d):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)}  }  ]  ] [. { \formula{\lambda m. \forall x \exists z [company' (z)  \land R.of(x, z)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow \exists y [sample' (y) \land saw'(x, y)]} \\ \formula{((e \linimp t)}  } [.\node (re) {$m : e$}; ] [.{ \formula{\forall x \exists z [company' (z)  \land R.of(x, z)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow \exists y [sample' (y) \land saw'(x, y)]} \\ \formula{t} } [.{ \formula{\lambda Q. \forall x \exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land R.of(x, z) \rightarrow Q(x)} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} }  [.{ \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall x [P (x)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Q(x)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))}} ] [.{\formula{\lambda n. \exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land R.of(n',z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t} }     [.\node (ue) {$n : e$}; ] [.{\formula{\exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land R.of(n',z)]: t} }          [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} \hspace{0.1cm} } [.{\formula{\lambda P.\lambda Q. \exists z [P(z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} }  ] [.{ \formula{\lambda d. company'(d):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)}  } ]             ] [.{\formula{\lambda l. R.of(n',l'):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} }       [.\node (ne) {$l : e$}; ] [.{\formula{R.of(n',l'):} \\ \formula{(t)} }       [.\node [circle,draw] (le) {$n : e$} ; ] [.{\formula{\lambda x. R.of(x,l'):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} }       [.{\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. R.of(x,y):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp } \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} } ] [.{\formula{l':e} }     [. {\formula{\lambda x_e. x_e:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp e)} } ] [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {$l' : e$} ; ] ] ]         ]                ]             ] ]         ] [.{\formula{\lambda k'. saw(k',m):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} } [.\node (te) {$k' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k',m'):} \\ \formula{t} }          [.\node [circle,draw] (se) {$k' : e$} ; ] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m'):} \\ \formula{(e  \linimp  t)} }   [.{\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp} \\ \formula{(e  \linimp  t)} } ] [.\node [circle,draw] (pe) {$m : e$} ; ] ] ]                  ]             ]           ] ] 
  \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:10) and +(south:10)    .. (ue);   
  \draw[semithick, dashed, ->]
  (me)..controls +(south west:11) and +(south:11) .. (ne);
  \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (se)..controls +(south west:1) and +(south:1) .. (te);    
  \draw[overlay,semithick, dashed, ->] (pe)..controls +(south:8) and  (south:50) .. (re);    
\end{tikzpicture}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}, level distance = 17ex, scale= 0.5]   
   \Tree  [.t [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} \hspace{0.1cm} } [.{\formula{\lambda P.\lambda Q. \exists z [P(z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} } ] [.{ \formula{\lambda d. company'(d):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)}  } ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda l'. \exists z [sample' (z)} \\ \formula{\land ]:} \\ \formula{\forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, z)]:}    \\ \formula{e \linimp t} \hspace{0.1cm} }      [.\node (ne) {$l' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{\exists z [sample' (z)} \\ \formula{\land ]:} \\ \formula{\forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, z)]:}    \\ \formula{t} \hspace{0.1cm} }       [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists z [sample' (z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} \hspace{0.1cm} } [.{\formula{\lambda P.\lambda Q. \exists z [P(z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} } ] [.{ \formula{\lambda d. sample'(d):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)}  } ] ] [.{ \formula{\lambda m'. \forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, m')]:} \\ \formula{e \linimp t} }        [.\node (re) {$m : e$}; ] [.{ \formula{\forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, m')]:} \\ \formula{t} }           [.{ \formula{\lambda Q. \forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Q(x)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} }          [.{ \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall x [P (x)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Q(x)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))}} ] [.{\formula{\lambda n'. R.of(n',l'):} \\ \formula{e \linimp t} }            [.\node (ue) {$n' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{R.of(n',l'):} \\ \formula{t} }                 [.\node [circle,draw] (le) {$n' : e$} ; ] [.{\formula{\lambda x. R.of(x,l'):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} }       [.{\formula{\lambda y \lambda x. R.of(x,y):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} }  ] [. \formula{l : e} [.{\formula{\lambda x_e. x_e:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp e)} } ] [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {$l' : e$} ; ]     ]       ]    ] ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda k'. saw(k',m'):} \\ \formula{e \linimp t} }     [.\node (te) {$k' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k',m'):} \\ \formula{t} }       [.\node [circle,draw] (se) {$k' : e$} ; ] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m'):} \\ \formula{(e  \linimp  t)} }  [.{\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp} \\ \formula{(e  \linimp  t)} } ] [.\node [circle,draw] (pe) {$m : e$} ; ] ]      ] ] ]            ]    ] ]                                                               ] 
 \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:1) and +(south:1) .. (ue);
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->]
  (me)..controls +(south west:15) and +(south:15) .. (ne);
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (se)..controls +(south west:1) and +(south:1) .. (te); 
\draw[overlay,semithick, dashed, ->] (pe)..controls +(south:20) and +(south west:10) .. (re.south);  
\end{tikzpicture}  

  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}, level distance = 15ex, scale= 0.5]   
   \Tree  [.t [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists z [sample' (z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} \hspace{0.1cm} } [.{\formula{\lambda P.\lambda Q. \exists z [P(z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} } ] [.{ \formula{\lambda d. sample'(d):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)}  } ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda m'. \exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land \forall x [R.of(x,z)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, m')]]:} \\ \formula{t} \hspace{0.1cm} }  [.\node (re) {$m' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{\exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land \forall x [R.of(x,z)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, m')]]:} \\ \formula{t} \hspace{0.1cm} }       [.{\formula{\lambda Q. \exists z [company' (z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} \hspace{0.1cm} } [.{\formula{\lambda P.\lambda Q. \exists z [P(z)} \\ \formula{\land Q(z)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))} } ] [.{ \formula{\lambda d. company'(d):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)}  } ] ] [.{ \formula{\lambda l'. \forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, m')]:} \\ \formula{e \linimp t} }  [.\node (ne) {$l' : e$}; ] [.{ \formula{\forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Saw(x, m')]:} \\ \formula{t} }       [.{ \formula{\lambda Q. \forall x [R.of(x,l')} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Q(x)]:} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))}}       [.{ \formula{\lambda P. \lambda Q. \forall x [P (x)} \\ \formula{\rightarrow Q(x)]:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)\linimp} \\ \formula{(\forall X(e \linimp X)} \\ \formula{\linimp X))}} ] [.{\formula{\lambda n'. R.of(n',l'):} \\ \formula{e \linimp t} }         [.\node (ue) {$n' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{R.of(n',l'):} \\ \formula{t} }     [.\node [circle,draw] (le) {$n' : e$} ; ] [.{\formula{\lambda x. R.of(x,l'):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp t)} }    [.{\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. R.of(x,y):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp} \\ \formula{e \linimp t)} } ] [. \formula{l : e} [.{\formula{\lambda x_e. x_e:} \\ \formula{(e \linimp e)} }  ] [.\node [circle,draw] (me) {$l' : e$} ; ]    ]     ]    ] ] ] [.{\formula{\lambda k'. saw(k',m'):} \\ \formula{e \linimp t} }         [.\node (te) {$k' : e$}; ] [.{\formula{saw(k',m'):} \\ \formula{t} }        [.\node [circle,draw] (se) {$k' : e$} ; ] [.{\formula{\lambda x. saw(x,m'):} \\ \formula{(e  \linimp  t)} }           [.{\formula{\lambda y\lambda x. saw(x,y):} \\ \formula{(e \linimp} \\ \formula{(e  \linimp  t)} }    ] [.\node [circle,draw] (pe) {$m' : e$} ; ] ]      ] ] ]            ]    ] ]                                                               ] 
 \draw[semithick, dashed, ->] (le)..controls +(south west:1) and +(south:1) .. (ue);
\draw[semithick, dashed, ->]
  (me)..controls +(south west:11) and +(south:11) .. (ne);
\draw[overlay,semithick, dashed, ->] (se)..controls +(south west:1) and +(south:1) .. (te); 
\draw[overlay,semithick, dashed, ->] (pe)..controls +(south:25) and +(south west:15) .. (re);  
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, you will need to use either some `overlay`s (as I did in my answer) or clipping to prevent control points to enlarge too much the bounding box.

Comment: Linimp does not appear in your diagrams, but it does in mine.

Comment: @user65526 Read the initial part of my answer. Since you didn't provide the definition I provided a fake temporary one to make the code compilable.

Comment: @user65526 If this answer solves your problem please consider accepting the question (and up-vote it).